# How to replace style property with proxy

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsdom, es6-proxy

I have code like this in my unit tests for jQuery Terminal:

```
// https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/135
Object.defineProperties(window.HTMLElement.prototype, {
    offsetLeft: {
        get: function() { return parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(this).marginLeft) || 0; }
    },
    offsetTop: {
        get: function() { return parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(this).marginTop) || 0; }
    },
    offsetHeight: {
        get: function() { return parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(this).height) || 0; }
    },
    offsetWidth: {
        get: function() { return parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(this).width) || 0; }
    },
    // this will test if setting 1ch change value to 1ch which don't work in jsdom used by jest
    style: {
        get: function() {
            if (this.__style) {
                return this.__style;
            }
            var self = this;
            var attr = {};
            function set_style_attr() {
                var str = Object.keys(attr).map((key) => `${key}: ${attr[key]}`).join(';') + ';';
                self.setAttribute('style', str);
            }
            var mapping = {
                backgroundClip: 'background-clip',
                className: 'class'
            };
            var reversed_mapping = {};
            Object.keys(mapping).forEach(key => {
                reversed_mapping[mapping[key]] = key;
            });
            return this.__style = new Proxy({}, {
                set: function(target, name, value) {
                    name = mapping[name] || name;
                    if (!value) {
                        delete target[name];
                        delete attr[name];
                    } else {
                        attr[name] = target[name] = value;
                    }
                    set_style_attr();
                    return true;
                },
                get: function(target, name) {
                    if (name === 'setProperty') {
                        return function(name, value) {
                            attr[name] = target[name] = value;
                            set_style_attr();
                        };
                    } else {
                        return target[name];
                    }
                },
                deleteProperty: function(target, name) {
                    name = reversed_mapping[name] || name;
                    delete target[name];
                    delete attr[name];
                    set_style_attr();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

It works for 1ch attribute in my tests that look like this:

```
    it('should handle wider characters without formatting', function() {
        var input = 'ターミナルウィンドウは黒[[;;]です]';
        var string = $.terminal.format(input, {char_width: 7});
        expect(string).toEqual('<span style="width: 24ch"><span style="widt'+
                               'h: 24ch">ターミナルウィンドウは黒</span></span'+
                               '><span style="width: 4ch" data-text="です">'+
                               '<span style="width: 4ch">です</span></span>');
    });
```

If I don't use my Proxy I got width in pixels, because I have code like this to check if ch is supported in my code:

```
var agent = window.navigator.userAgent;
var is_IE = /MSIE|Trident/.test(agent) || /rv:11.0/i.test(agent);
var is_IEMobile = /IEMobile/.test(agent);
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
var is_ch_unit_supported = (function() {
    if (is_IE && !is_IEMobile) {
        return false;
    }
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.width = '1ch';
    return div.style.width === '1ch';
})();
```

The problem is when I want to check the style property to get some value, like this test:

```
    it('should find inside formatting', function() {
        term.less(big_text.concat(['[[;red;]foo bar baz]']));
        search('bar');
        var spans = term.find('[data-index="0"] > div:first-child span');
        ['foo ', 'bar', ' baz'].forEach(function(string, i) {
            expect(a0(spans.eq(i).text())).toEqual(string);
        });
        [true, false, true].forEach(function(check, i) {
            console.log(spans.get(i).style.getPropertyValue('color'));
            expect([i, !!spans.get(i).attr('style').match(/color:\s*red/)]).toEqual([i, check]);
        });
    });
```

I've tried:

```
spans.get(i).style.getPropertyValue('color')
```

This return error that's not a function and

```
spans.get(i).attr('style')
```

is undefined. This also don't work

```
spans.get(i).getAttribute('style')
```

which should be the same and the one before.

Is there a way to have `ch` unit support check work but in same way getting values from style attribute as well?

I'm using jest framework that use jsDom I running my tests from Node.

I've tried to create `getPropertyValue` function in `get` trap for the proxy but I don't know how to get original function so I can call it.

So to sum up, I need solution in jsDOM that allow to set width to 1ch and get that value back (so my code don't change), and that should work when creating new HTMLElement in DOM and get it's value out of, It don't need to be style object with props it can be style property as string. Alternative solution is to test if ch unit is supported that will work in jsDOM.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue by temporarily disabling getter when accessing properties:

```
(function() {
    var style_descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.HTMLElement.prototype, 'style');

    Object.defineProperties(window.HTMLElement.prototype, {
        offsetLeft: {
            get: function() { return parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(this).marginLeft) || 0; }
        },
        offsetTop: {
            get: function() { return parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(this).marginTop) || 0; }
        },
        offsetHeight: {
            get: function() { return parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(this).height) || 0; }
        },
        offsetWidth: {
            get: function() { return parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(this).width) || 0; }
        },
        // this will test if setting 1ch change value to 1ch which don't work in jsdom used by jest
        style: {
            get: function getter() {
                if (this.__style) {
                    return this.__style;
                }
                var self = this;
                var attr = {};
                function set_style_attr() {
                    var str = Object.keys(attr).map((key) => `${key}: ${attr[key]}`).join(';') + ';';
                    self.setAttribute('style', str);
                }
                var mapping = {
                    backgroundClip: 'background-clip',
                    className: 'class'
                };
                var reversed_mapping = {};
                Object.keys(mapping).forEach(key => {
                    reversed_mapping[mapping[key]] = key;
                });
                function disable(fn) {
                    // temporary disable proxy
                    Object.defineProperty(window.HTMLElement.prototype, "style", style_descriptor);
                    var ret = fn();
                    Object.defineProperty(window.HTMLElement.prototype, "style", {
                        get: getter
                    });
                    return ret;
                }
                return this.__style = new Proxy({}, {
                    set: function(target, name, value) {
                        name = mapping[name] || name;
                        if (!value) {
                            delete target[name];
                            delete attr[name];
                        } else {
                            attr[name] = target[name] = value;
                        }
                        set_style_attr();
                        disable(function() {
                            self.style[name] = name;
                        });
                        return true;
                    },
                    get: function(target, name) {
                        if (name === 'setProperty') {
                            return function(name, value) {
                                attr[name] = target[name] = value;
                                set_style_attr();
                            };
                        } else if (target[name]) {
                            return target[name];
                        } else {
                            return disable(function() {
                                return self.style[name];
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    deleteProperty: function(target, name) {
                        name = reversed_mapping[name] || name;
                        delete target[name];
                        delete attr[name];
                        disable(function() {
                            delete self.style[name];
                        });
                        set_style_attr();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
})();
```